# Oracle SQL TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ Format issue ORA-01843: not a valid month

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, timezone-offset

I have a TABLEA in below format (Updated Columns has Pacific TZ adjusted against UTC)

| Status | Updated |
| --- | --- |
| Complete | 09/Mar/2021 08:27:30AM -1100 |
| Apps Tasks | 04/Mar/2021 12:42:12AM -1100 |
| Complete | 11/Mar/2021 09:27:30AM -1100 |
| Complete | 12/Feb/2021 10:27:30AM -1100 |

I used below query and I get data as expected but it seems I am messing up date/Timestamp format as I am getting "ORA-01843: not a valid month" in Oracle Apex when I use below query to generate graph.I have been tweaking the query with to_date,to_char,trunc and combinations of TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ and NLS_LANGUAGE but seem to be going in circle.Any inputs would be appreciated if I am missing something in the formatting on the query ?

```
select TRUNC(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(UPDATED),'MONTH') AS Month,COUNT(STATUS) AS "Complete" FROM TABLEA
where STATUS='Complete'
group by TRUNC(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(UPDATED), 'MONTH')
order by TRUNC(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(UPDATED), 'MONTH')
```

| MONTH | Complete |
| --- | --- |
| 02/01/2021 | 1 |
| 03/01/2021 | 2 |

Thanks

Comment: Fix your data model so date/time values are stored using appropriate types rather than strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should fix the data model to store date/time values using the appropriate time stamp **which is not a string**.

Second, I would return the results using dates:

```
select trunc(to_date(substr(update, 1, 11), 'DD/MMM/YYYY'), 'MON') as yyyymm,
       count(*)
from t
group by trunc(to_date(substr(update, 1, 11), 'DD/MMM/YYYY'), 'MON');
```

You can, of course, format the first column however you want using `to_char()`.  However, I want to emphasize that your data and your code should be using `date`s or `timestamp`s.